# Customizable workflow/ State machine

Tags: java, workflow

I am trying to build a customizable workflow or kind of state transition which user should be able to update through UI. 
Basically it should have all the states and user should be able to choose the transition from one state to another and also hook any predefined action to it. The predefined action could be anything like user task, email task or script task.

It should be flexible enough to add more states / actions to it.

I tried evaluating Activiti but it doesn't look like a good fit here. In fact Workflow engine doesn't look like a right candidate.

Can someone suggest any existing framework or library which I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have chosen Squirrel foundation as my backend state transition machine. Decorated with my custom palates for denoting different kind of state (user intervention, service , email etc). And using Viz.js for visualizing and creating the workflow in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JBPM.  I have used it in my earlier project.

http://www.jbpm.org/[Jbpm Home][1].

Drawback

JBPM 5 doesnt support clustering. (Not sure if It is fixed in JBPM 6)

Comment: Do you think jbpm fit in this requirement. BPD has to be versioned every time someoe changes the workflow. I was thinking workflow engine is not a right candidate in this scenario. Some state machine can do job.

Comment: As per mentioned scenario, User needs to complete certain task like sending email, etc. This can be achieved using Human task. Also single Human task can be completed by single user. If this is not your scenario then workflow is not suited to your requirement. Also, for using a workflow, you will need to define workflow cycle which will be static.   Also can you provide examples of some state machines?

Comment: Something like [Apache SCXML](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-scxml/index.html)